# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) socket python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to make a little program which needs two clients and a server. Basically I want to send JSON from client 1 to client 2, (which client 1 has received from the server), but it doesn't work. From client 1 to the server does work though. I use a new socket connection to send from client 1 to client 2 (this is mandatory for my assignment).
I get these errors:

```
File "C:\Users\duser\OneDrive\Bureaublad\clientt.py", line 105, in <module>
    client2()
  File "C:\Users\duser\OneDrive\Bureaublad\clientt.py", line 75, in client2
    newdict = json.loads(receiveclient1)
  File "C:\Users\duser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\duser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\duser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is the code:

```
import socket
import json
import sys

i = 0

host = "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"
port = 55550
port2 = 44445
obj = socket.socket()
s = socket.socket()

hostname = socket.gethostname()
complete_info = ''

clientinfo = {"studentnr1": "0982130",
              "studentnr2": "0943260",
              "classname": "INF",
              "clientid": 1,
              "teamname":"Team",
              "ip":socket.gethostbyname(hostname),
              "secret": "",
              "status": ""}


def client1():
    global complete_info, newdict
    obj.connect((host,port))
    while True:
        data = obj.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        complete_info = data.decode("utf-8")
        print(complete_info)
        
        clientinfosend = str.encode(json.dumps(clientinfo))
        obj.sendall(clientinfosend)
        inforeceive = obj.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        inforeceived = json.loads(inforeceive)
        print(inforeceived)
    
    s.connect((socket.gethostbyname(hostname),port2))
    s.sendall(str.encode(json.dumps(inforeceived)))
    obj.close()
    print("Connection closed")
       

def client2():
    #while loop which listens to connection from client 1
    s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(hostname), port2))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Listening for connections")
    while True:
        print('Connection from', addr)
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if not data:
            break

    receiveclient1 = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    
    newdict = json.loads(receiveclient1)
    print(newdict)
    temp = newdict["studentnr1"]
    newdict["studentnr1"] = newdict["studentnr2"]
    newdict["studentnr2"] = temp
    newdict["clientid"] = sys.argv[1]
    
    s.close()


num_arguments = len(sys.argv[1:])
i = 1
args = sys.argv[1:]

if int(sys.argv[i]) == 1:
    client1()

elif int(sys.argv[i]) == 2:
    client2()
```

Comment: Did you try printing the JSON you’re attempting to decode…?

Comment: yeah the line which says print(newdict)

Comment: No, before decoding, not after decoding. `print(receiveclient1)`

Comment: oh okay, it prints this ```{'studentnr1': '0982130', 'studentnr2': '0943260', 'classname': 'INF', 'clientid': 1, 'teamname': 'Team', 'ip': 'xxx.xxx.xx.x', 'secret': '2ba2b281920b0e2a2da34686013bec02ee399488f44bf0ec2ae9471694c71f35', 'status': 'waiting for message 2'}``` and this needs to be sent to client 2 from client 1

Comment: Well, that’s not JSON. Looks like a Python dict…

Comment: probably is but that method worked from client 1 to the server. But from client 1 to client 2 gives me that error, do you know why maybe?

Comment: Your terminology is confused. "client2" is a server. It's unclear which other server you are talking to.

Comment: client2 will be temporarily used as a server. When client2 receives the data it changes the json values and then a new socket will be made (3rd socket) which will send it back to the original server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In client2, you first read the socket until it is shut down or closed with:

```
while True:
    print('Connection from', addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    if not data:
        break
```

That means that when you exit that loop, no data can come from the socket.

So in next lines:

```
receiveclient1 = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
newdict = json.loads(receiveclient1)
```

`receiveclient1` is an empty string, which explains the error.

You should instead build `receiveclient1` from the `data` fragments:

```
receiveclient1 = ''
while True:
    print('Connection from', addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    if not data:
        break
    receiveclient1 += data

newdict = json.loads(receiveclient1)
```